# Probability of multivariant gaussian random variables in different areas

Tags: pr.probability, integration, expectation

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$Let $X_i$ is a gaussian random variable correlated with others. we want to find the probability of each possible case to find the expectation of following expression

$\mathbb{E} [\sgn(X_1) \sgn(X_2) \sgn(X_3) \sgn(X_4)] = \mathbb P(X_1>0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0) - \mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0) + \ldots$

here we have the closed form for $\mathbb P(X_1>0, X_2>0, X_3>0, X_4>0)$ based on this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280. but unfortunately not for other terms.

Please guide if you can. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think we just need to find closed form for $\mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2<0, X_3>0, X_4>0)$

Comment: That linked question considered only random variables with zero mean — for non-zero means I think you’ll find that you don’t have a formula.

Comment: @Matt F.
 Yes, in my case also, all variables are zero mean. But the problem that confused me is all correlation matrix entries have to be non-negative in that closed form (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280.)

Comment: What do you want to do with the closed-form expression?

Comment: @ Matt F.
Having the closed-form expression for each probability term, I can find the closed form for that expected value.

Comment: Since no reason has been given for finding a closed-form expression, and since the linked question shows that any such expression would be so messy as to provide little insight, I have down-voted the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141228/discussion-between-amin-radbord-and-matt-f).

Comment: @MattF. : Such probabilities are used in statistics and elsewhere. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5448 and references [22, 21, 5, 10, 15] there, and then further references in [21, 5].

Comment: The assumptions look incomplete. First, you should assume that the vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_4)$ is gaussian and not only its components $X_i$. Nest do you assume taht the $X_i$ is centered?  If yes, write it explicitly.

Comment: @ Christophe Leuridan
Yes, the vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4)$ is zero-mean gaussian random vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $P(X_1>0,X_2>0,X_3>0,X_3>0)$ for any multivariate Gaussian random vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$, then you know all such probabilities. E.g.,, $P(X_1<0,X_2<0,X_3>0,X_3>0)=P(Y_1>0,Y_2>0,Y_3>0,Y_4>0)$, where $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4):=(-X_1,-X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is multivariate Gaussian as well.

Similarly, if you know $P(X_1>0,X_2>0,X_3>0,X_3>0)$ for any zero-mean multivariate Gaussian random vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$, then you know all such probabilities. E.g.,, $P(X_1<0,X_2<0,X_3>0,X_3>0)=P(Y_1>0,Y_2>0,Y_3>0,Y_4>0)$, where $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4):=(-X_1,-X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is zero-mean multivariate Gaussian as well.

---

**Added:** According to a comment by the OP, the $X_i$'s are, in fact, zero-mean. In that case, one can express each of the probabilities in questions as the sum of $\binom42=6$ ordinary integrals each with an integrand that is the product of an algebraic expression and the $\arctan$ of an algebraic expression. This is done by formulas (7) and (6) of [Plackett](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332716). Here the signs of the correlation coefficients do not matter, and the integrals are much, much simpler than the ones in the answer you linked in your post.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But the problem is all correlation coefficient in that closed form solution has to be non-negative (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280). so how can I found other probabilities like $\mathbb P(X_1<0,X_2<0,X_3>0,X_4>0)$

Comment: @AminRadbord : I have added a response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. can you please explain about this part in math detail, '6  ordinary integrals each with an integrand that is the product of an algebraic factor and the arctan of an algebraic factor' ? I couldn't follow this part.

Comment: By the way, I think it's not closed-form, it seems to end up with a numerical integral.

Comment: @AminRadbord : (i) In Plackett's formula (7), we have the sum over all pairs $i<j$, both $i$ and $j$ being in the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in your case, and there are $\binom42=6$ such pairs. Then use Plackett's formula (6), with $n=4$ and $a_i=b_i=0$ in your case. The factor in the first line of (6) is algebraic (in $\rho_{12}$). In the second line of (6), you have $\Phi_{n-2}=\Phi_2$ in your case, so that $\Phi_{n-2}(\cdots)$ is a certain angle measure, which is the $\arctan$ of an algebraic expression in terms of the $\rho_{ij}$'s.

Comment: @AminRadbord :  (ii) The sum of the 6 ordinary integrals mentioned in my answer is clearly the very best one can have. I understand you wanted closed-form expressions, but such expressions do not exist. Also, as I wrote, these 6 ordinary integrals are much, much simpler than the ones in the answer you linked in your post.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis
Thank you so much. I really appreciate your solution definitely it's simpler. However, I checked that link as a closed form solution and I found something interesting. If you notice you can see actually $\mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2<0,X_3>0,X_4>0) = \mathbb P(X_1>0, X_2>0,X_3>0,X_4>0) $, since the sign of all parameters are exactly the same from $\delta$ to $v_2$. (actually you have to  put $a_{1,3}' = -a_{1,3},a_{1,4}' = -a_{1,4}, a_{2,3}' = -a_{2,3}, a_{2,4}' = -a_{2,4}$).

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis
Then to find other terms like $\mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2>0,X_3>0,X_4<0) $ that actually have different sign for those resulting parameters in that closed-form (I mean $\delta$,...,$v_2$), we can change variables order and so change correlation matrix, or in another word:
$\mathbb P(X_1<0, X_2>0,X_3>0,X_4<0) $ = $\mathbb P(X_1<0, X_4<0,X_2>0,X_3>0) $ where $a_{1,2}' = a_{1,4},a_{1,3}' = a_{1,2}, a_{1,4}' = a_{1,3}, a_{2,2}' = a_{4,4},a_{2,1}' = a_{4,1},a_{2,3}' = a_{4,2},a_{2,4}' = a_{4,3} $

Comment: @AminRadbord : I don't think that the two probabilities in your penultimate comment are the same in general. Indeed, suppose that $X_2$ is very close to $X_1$, and $X_4$ is very close to $X_3$. Then the two probabilities are very close to $P(X_1<0,X_3>0)$ and $P(X_1>0,X_3>0)$, which are unequal if $X_1$ and $X_3$ are correlated (say, if $X_3$ is close to $X_1$).

Comment: @AminRadbord : Do you have a further response to the answer and my comments?

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis
No, your last comment was right. I stopped at finding the closed form. If I could just find $\mathbb P(X_1<0,X_2<0,X_3>0,X_4>0)$ in closed form, I could definitely find the closed form for the expectation but there's no way for that.

Comment: @AminRadbord : So, if you agree that the sum of those 6 ordinary integrals is the best one can have here, can you please wrap up this matter?

Comment: @losif Pinelis
Do you have any idea about this approach, please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437163/taylor-series-for-multidimensional-orthant-probability

Comment: @AminRadbord : What do you mean by "this approach"? At https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437163/taylor-series-for-multidimensional-orthant-probability , what do you mean by "last comment"? Anyhow, before proceeding further, let us finalize the matter on this very page.

Comment: @  Iosif Pinelis
This approach https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs00454-006-1253-4. 'Measuring Solid Angles Beyond Dimension Three'.

Comment: @AminRadbord : So, there are expressions in terms of Taylor series. What do you then mean by asking "Do you have any idea about this approach"? I still think that -- for dimension $4$ as in your post -- $6$ ordinary integrals are better than the Taylor series.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis
Actually, If you see somehow (that I can not understand exactly how) multi-exponent terms replaced by infinite taylor series (at least I can not see any infinite terms there). Also the athour gives a discussion about convergence (so if it can converge, it means it can be approximated by finite terms). Also someone could implement it  in R-code https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals/3148280#3148280 (answered by Sextus Empiricus, However personally I don't know anything about this kind of code).

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis: so as a result I guess we can have an approximated closed-form expression, that can be implemented, for any arbitrary covariance matrix, since there is no imposed constraint for the inverse of covariance matrix $\mathbf A$

Comment: @AminRadbord : (i) The Taylor series is, in your case, in $\binom42=6$ variables. Such a series will have a huge number of terms, $\binom{n+5}5$, of order $n$, even for a moderately large order $n$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710875/how-many-n-th-order-partial-derivatives-exist-for-a-function-of-k-variables). On the other hand, to have a small remainder (**bounds on which are not given in the paper**), you will likely need the order $n$ to be large.

Comment: Previous comment continued: (ii) It is unclear from the paper if the series will always converge. The statement of Theorem 3.2 about the convergence and its proof are unclear. (iii) All this makes the Taylor series unusable. (iv) On the other hand, using some of the many well-known methods, it is easy to compute the 6 ordinary integrals to any degree of accuracy. It is also possible to analyze properties of the integral expression, as was done e.g. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.5448